# What use is a dummy heat sink assembly?

Tags: ibm-xseries, hardware

Cleaning out our server room, we found two of these:

[IBM eServer xSeries dummy heatsink assembly](http://www.impactcomputers.com/26k6065.html)

[image: IBM eServer xSeries dummy heatsink assembly]

I can't find any documentation on what they were used for (presumably during shipping or for a multi-socket Xeon board with only 1 CPU installed); can anyone tell me what they are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Dell servers that often stipulate special blank covers must be fitted over other blanks that may be filled by parts not present (esp Hard Drive Bays/PSU's) for thermal issues.

It wouldn't surprise me if the people who designed that server did some complicated analysis of airflow, and the results made them decide to supply a whole processor/heatsink blank to ensure a predetermined amount of airflow over the rest of the components.

Edit: Unless they were just trying to make life easy for a newbie who had never seen a 2nd CPU slot on a motherboard and didn't know where to fit the damn thing.

Comment: The "front" label and arrow did make me think it had something to do with airflow. I think you've nailed it.

Comment: +1 I've seen this with dell too. They _love_ to have blanks where items are missing to maintain a specific airflow design.  It's very fancy fluid dynamics stuff.

Comment: this is exactly right.  Same reason you need the blanks on the hard drive bays

Comment: Airflow is indeed the reason. This has become quite critical as component densities and heat generation have increased. For those who might doubt this I can only suggest you take temperature measurements with and without the dummy/blanking piece.

Answer (score 0):

It's for controlling the airflow - without the blank there would be a huge void space which will generate nearly no resistance to the airflow - and so will take away airflow where it is needed - like the heatsink of the real CPU - possible generating all kinds of thermal problems.